# Invoke GetDeferral on ContentDialog's Custom Buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I have a `ContentDialog` that I use as an object CRUD operations. I use `MessageDialog` during verification to alarm user any missing info etc. It was fine if I use it with the default `PrimaryButtonClick` as it's click event parameter, `ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs` has `GetDeferral()` method which can be used to alter the default setting where closing any `MessageDialog` will also close the parent `ContentDialog`.

However when I use custom buttons, the event parameter is `RoutedEventArgs` and does not contain `GetDeferral()`

Example:

```
//This works fine. ValidateForm() will call MessageDialog as alarms/warnings 
private async void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
{
     //save item
     var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
     args.Cancel = await ValidateForm();
     deferral.Complete();
}
```

But his returns compilation error:

```
private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var deferral = e.GetDeferral();
     e.Cancel = await ValidateForm();
     deferral.Complete();
}
```

What should I do to enable GetDeferral on normal/custom buttons click event? Should I cast the parameter as `ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs`? Will that work? Any better work around?

Comment: You may try, but I doubt it will work. But I don't think you'll need to use deferral with custom button since clicking it should not automatically close the `ContentDialog`.

Comment: Custom button does not close the `ContentDialog`. But, `MessageDialog` that comes when custom button clicked will close the `ContentDialog` when it was closed. Example, when I click the custom button, it will check something then will popup `MessageDialog` to user. Closing this `MessageDialog` will actually close the parent `ContentDialog` too.

Comment: So the question to you is, why do you use a custom button given there's already built-in ones that are designed for this purpose?

Comment: @JustinXL I need extra buttons that is why

Comment: I have a [deferral manager here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/5.0.0-pre-05) that you might be able to use to build a solution.

Comment: @HaikalNashuha how you solved?